# what does this translate to in english?

Tags: перевод, транслитерация, английский

What does this translate to in English? ПРЕВЬЫШЕНА НАГРУЗКА на сервер. ведется техоБслуживание.

Comment: Are you not the person who asked the exact same question yesterday on Reddit? See https://www.reddit.com/r/russian/comments/5amrcx/hi_i_was_looking_for_some_help_to_translate_this/

Comment: @KCd Everybody's asking this question now. http://volskayaindustries.com

Basically, this is viral/alternate reality marketing for a soon-to-be-unveiled new hero in the game Overwatch. It involves a lot of code-breaking and clue hunting. There's a location in the game that's set in a futuristic Russia.

Answer (score 2):

`Server overload. [The system] is being serviced`. There are several misprints in the original message.